# on Event Clicked issue

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I'm using Bootstrap 4 Beta and JavaScript for my university project, I'm making some calendar event function. and I'm used [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/)  for popup, my issue is When I click the calendar event alert is display but this alert cant customize ,I want to know how to added `<div>` `<button>` `text` and `etc` for this alert, look my attached image, you can understand it

This is my script,

**event**

```
 dp.events.list = [{
      start: "2017-12-20",
      end: "2017-12-28",
      id: "1",
         resource: "A",
      text: "Mahesh",
      backColor: "#70CB85",


    },
```

**click**

```
dp.onEventClicked = function(args) {
 bootbox.alert(" " + args.e.text()); //Alert
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from their [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#basic-usage-3):

> An alert callback should not supply an argument; it will be ignored

If you want to pass a button you can use `confirm`:

```
bootbox.confirm({
    message: "This is a confirm with custom button text and color! Do you like it?",
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Yes',
            className: 'btn-success'
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'No',
            className: 'btn-danger'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Or use Dialog:

```
bootbox.dialog({ message: '<div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Loading...</div>' })
```

Comment: Thanks sir , my fault Im added `argument;` now its work

Answer (score 2):

you can put html in alert easily .

```
bootbox.alert("Your message <b>here…</b>")
```

see [this link](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-alert-dialog) for more option of alert